# Delete older than N days distinct entries

Tags: sql, oracle, sybase, sap-ase

I have to delete data for each Account + date_added combination which is more than N days old.
By N days old, it means here deleting older than first N distinct occurrences for above combination

```
DELETE
FROM tbl_check 
   WHERE
   N  <  (SELECT count(DISTINCT date_added) + 1
   FROM tbl_check b
   WHERE b.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = tbl_check.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
     AND tbl_check.date_added < b.date_added)
```

This query must run on both Sybase ASE and Oracle. I have written so far above query which is trying to simulate DENSE_RANK and is successfully deleting based on ranking.

However it does not use any index and is also a correlated query doing a FTS. There could be thousands of rows in this table.
[image]

There is a composite PK which is : FOREIGN_KEY_COL , ACCOUNT_NUMBER, date_added , ..
Is this query up to the job or we can improve upon it given same query has to work on both databases as mentioned.

Comment: Also some way to make this DELETE buffered would be nice

Answer (score 0):

why you dont use below query ;

```
DELETE FROM tbl_check  where (getdate()-date_added)> N
```

Comment: this is because date_added is not same for each account_number and so for Account1 , data_added could be SYSDATE , SYSDATE -1 , SYSDATE -2 . Account2 can have only SYSDATE -2, SYSDATE -4, SYSDATE -5. If N = 2 , then after cleanup, Account1 should delete SYSDATE -2 and account2 should delete SYSDATE -5